# MySQL form builder like MS Access

Tags: software-rec, mysql, microsoft-access

Are there any good tools out there (don't have to be be free) that provide functionality analogous to MS Access but for non-MS databases like MySQL?  I'm looking for more than just a query builder like MySQL Workbench.  But something that allows power users to build read/write forms to modify database contents, and then non-power users to use those forms.

Of course there are a zillion web development solutions to this problem.  What I'm looking for is something that allows somebody who's technical but not really a developer to easily create forms that allow others to modify a database.

Ideally the system would work on either windows or mac.  But if there's something great that's only available on one, we could deal with that.

Comment: What OS do the forms need to run under? What environment will you be making it under?

Comment: Good question.  Clarified.

Comment: @Leopd - Are you aware you can hook Access up as a front-end to a back-end MySQL server via ODBC?

Comment: For both Windows and Mac, I would suggest FileMaker, except it's not MySQL

Comment: I might also add, you can use MSSQL DBs generated by access as a backend for Django. If you're crazy, just like me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [Libre Office's "Base"](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/base/) would work for you? I've never tried it myself.

"there are a zillion web development solutions to this problem" -- like [Django](http://djangoproject.com)? Sort of applies.. I love Django, but I think you're looking for something created through a GUI.

Comment: LibreOffice Base is interesting because it's free but every users will need to install the software. I was looking for a free server-side web based solution, without having to code it. Btw I found that LibreOffice can also run on a web browser: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Using_LibreOffice_in_a_Web_Browser

Comment: I loathe Microsoft Access, but it does have some kind of web-delivered interface option. I wouldn't be surprised if that only worked well with IE. Anyway, that exists. Django is all about web delivered database driven applications. It's awesome. Just has no GUI to create with.

Answer (score 2):

Absent the Mac requirement (unless you're using Parallels) I would suggest that your best bet is Access. It has no trouble working with MySQL data.

Your question strikes me as quite odd because of that. The only part of Access that is limited to MS SQL data is ADP, but that's deprecated even for SQL Server these days in favor of MDB/ACCDB with ODBC linked tables. In that regard, MySQL is completely equivalent to SQL Server in terms of what's supported.